# Log Postgresql sequence value that is missing in main table

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, sequence

Gaps on id column occurs due to the usage of sequences on PostgreSQL as the default value of the table’s primary key. When the transaction rollback the sequence value will not rollback thus the id column will be not sequential. I have tried to eliminate the gaps but it seems to impact the performance. What I am thinking right now is to log those missing IDs along with error message and request payload. As a result, I am struggling getting the ID that was generated by sequence when DB transaction rollback.

Please suggest approach to get the missing sequence ID from DB when function is  rollbacked so we can log it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Best practice, unless there is a legal requirement, accept that gaps are perfectly normal and harmless. Move-on and do not even try to recover unused sequence values.